# Hardhat deploy specific script

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I have hardhat setup for a project, whose inital setup is to deploy the whole project e.g

```
01-deploy-timelock
02-deplot-governance-token
03-deploy-governance.
```

I would like to create a new script for upgrading the governance token e.g

04 upgrade-governance, however I don't want to run the other deploy scripts,  How can I run a specific deploy script in react?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy as superior way to manage deployments

I've created tool to bootstrap my hardhat projects, inside there is a basic example of deployment, you can find it here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/hardhat-create-app

Its worth nothing that you can specify dependencies of deployments, as well as tags for each deployment (both are very handy):
https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy#deploy-scripts-tags-and-dependencies

Tag usage:

```
npx hardhat deploy --tags YOUR_TAG
```

You can also use multiple tags separated by a comma

Answer (score 2):

I usually create hardhat task.

https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/advanced/create-task

Task can be named and run what ever code you want. You can run a specific task with the command line.